# sklearn.utils module is not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So I have `sklearn` installed, but for some reason whenever I try to `import sklearn` it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\joeya\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
from .base import clone
File "C:\Users\joeya\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 17, in <module>
from .utils import _IS_32BIT
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.utils'
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I have Python 3.8.7 installed.